# Dynamically Generated Modal Lightning Component, Button Not Working as Intended

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning

Creating a lightning component and I have two methods in the helper class which a) dynamically create two lightning components (buttons) and a modal popup and b) a method for the onclick of one of these buttons which closes the window.

The modal window is rendering correctly with the buttons as intended, but the "handleCancel" method is firing on modal load, NOT on the "onclick" of the button. Code is below, any suggestions are appreciated.

```
handleShowModal: function(component, evt, helper) {
    $A.createComponents(
        [
            ["lightning:button",
            {
                "aura:id": "cancelButton",
                "label": "Cancel",
                "onclick": helper.handleCancel(component)               
            }],
            ["lightning:button",
            {
                "aura:id": "mergeButton",
                "label": "Merge"
            }]
        ],
        function(comp, status) {
            if (status === "SUCCESS") {
                component.find('overlayLib').showCustomModal({
                    header: "Confirm Merge",
                    body: "Are you sure you wish to merge the below records?", 
                    footer: comp,
                    showCloseButton: true
                });
            }
        }
    );
},
//closes the modal
handleCancel : function(component) {
    console.log("button pressed");  
    console.log("the comp "+component.find("overlayLib"));
    component.find('overlayLib').notifyClose();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
handleShowModal: function(component, evt, helper) {
    $A.createComponents(
        [
            ["lightning:button",
            {
                "aura:id": "cancelButton",
                "label": "Cancel",
                "onclick": cmp.getReference("c.handleCancel")               
            }],
            ["lightning:button",
            {
                "aura:id": "mergeButton",
                "label": "Merge"
            }]
        ],
        function(comp, status) {
            if (status === "SUCCESS") {
                component.find('overlayLib').showCustomModal({
                    header: "Confirm Merge",
                    body: "Are you sure you wish to merge the below records?", 
                    footer: comp,
                    showCloseButton: true
                });
            }
        }
    );
}
```

Your handle cancel should be a function of js Controller.

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/js_cb_dynamic_cmp_async.htm

Comment: Thanks @Manjot that worked in that the handleCancel method will successfully be called on click of the button (I can see console logs in the browser). However, the actual closing of the modal isn't working. Is this the right method to do so? component.find("overlayLib").notifyClose();

Comment: I actually found this link here: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/193770/how-to-close-lightningoverlaylibrary-custom-modal/193928 which provides a valid solution. It appears the notifyClose has some problems. I'll mark your answer as best answer it was correct for my need but this other item should be referenced as well for others.