# lightning:overlayLibrary Modal not closing in LEX Tab

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, lightning-apps

I've been using lightning:overlayLibrary Modal in a component which is referred in a Lightning Page and in a Lightning Tab.
I'm using a custom button to close the modal which performs a `overlayPromise.close()` method of the promise returned by lightning:overlayLibrary.
I am able to close the modal by this way when the component is in Lightning Page. But, Fails to close the modal when the component is in a Lightning Tab.

[image]
And when I try to do the close action in the browser console, the modal gets closed.
It's weird.

**Component:**

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >
<lightning:overlayLibrary aura:id="overlayLib"/>
<aura:attribute name="overlayPanel" type="Aura.Component[]" />
<lightning:button name="modal" label="Show Modal" onclick="{!c.handleShowModal}"/>
```

**Controller:**

```
  ({
        handleShowModal: function(component, evt, helper) {
            var modalBody;
            $A.createComponent("lightning:button", {
                "label" : 'Close Modal',
                "onclick" : component.getReference("c.closeModal")
            },function(content, status) {
                if (status === "SUCCESS") {
                    modalBody = content;
                    component.find('overlayLib').showCustomModal({
                        header: "Overlay Modal",
                        body: modalBody, 
                        showCloseButton: true,
                        closeCallback: function() {
                            console.log('You closed the alert!');
                        }
                    }).then(function (overlay) {
                        component.set('v.overlayPanel', overlay);
                    });

                }

            });
        },
        closeModal : function(component,event,helper){
            console.log('closing');
            var overlayPanel = component.get('v.overlayPanel');
            console.log('overlayPanel',overlayPanel);
            overlayPanel[0].close();

        }
    })
```

***Additional Info:***
The same scenario throws the following error when used in packaging Orgs

> Access Check Failed! Component.method():'markup://ui:close' is not
>   visible to 'markup://*Org Namespace-URL*

[image]

**Stack Trace:**

> resolve()@https: //my-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/components/lightning-overlay-utils.js:200:33
>   OverlayPanel.close()@https: //my-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/components/lightning-overlay-utils.js:199:16
>   Object.closeCalendarModal()@https: /my-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/one/components/my_ns/Calendar.js:116:29
>   eval()@https ://my-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/one/components/my_ns/Calendar.js:137:28
>   Object.destroyHelper()@https ://my-dev-ed.lightning.force.com/one/components/my_ns/Calendar.js:139:49

Comment: Any chance you could post the Stack Trace as well?

Comment: Stack Trace added @Folkert

Comment: why do you save the returned reference to the modal as an array of components?

Comment: unable "component.find('overlayPanel')" inside the modal body. so we are storing an instance of it as an attribute to use it onclick of the button inside the modal body.

Answer (score 0):

I ran in this issue today as well.

For me, creating a custom modal footer component instead of using the promise returned object worked also in tab only context.

The approach is detailed in the docs with [`c:modalFooter`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:overlayLibrary/documentation) and in [this answer](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/230065/27272) which also contains discussion on debugging details and if this method is really, really the same as `close()` on the promise return object.

Personally, I would also prefer to work with the object returned by the promise.

For what it's worth, I didn't use a component attribute to store the modal reference but a temporary attribute/expando on `component`:

```
     component.myOverlay =  overlay
}
```

Access check fails in this instance as well.

What ultimately worked for me in both contexts was [this approach](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/210822/27272) using an `Aura.Action` attribute instead of an expando / cmp array attribute and calling it this way:

```
    Promise.resolve(component.get('v.modalPromise')).then(
      function (modal) {
          modal.close();
      }
  );
```